# Swift: Is there a faster way to hash an array of Ints than "\(array)"

Tags: swift, string, performance

I want to implement a `Dictionary` where the keys are type `String`.

The the String keys are generated by literally concatenating an array of `Int` (it's basically an address).

i.e. the hash of address [0, 10, 32] would be "01032".

The values never go above 255-- in fact I could use `[UInt8]`.

I did a little test in XCode and got decent performance. 0.036s for this:

```
func testPerformance() {
    let address = [10, 176, 12] //should become "1017612"
    self.measure {
         for _ in 0..<10_000 {
             let key = "\(address[0])\(address[1])\(address[2])"
         }
    }
}
```

My question: is there is a lighter weight String type or method that can do what I want faster than this? From what I understand, Swift's String class is quite heavyweight with all kinds of added character info underneath:

https://medium.com/@tonyallevato/strings-characters-and-performance-in-swift-a-deep-dive-b7b5bde58d53

Comment: So where's your actual code?

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: If you're looking for performance, why are you using computed Strings as Dictionary keys? How long can these addresses be? (Are they just IPv4 addresses represented as arrays of 4 UInt8s?)

Comment: Why not use a struct  that implements Hashable?

Comment: Or why not use Ints as your keys??

Comment: @Alexander: yes exactly-- much like an IP Address. No more than 4 bytes. But sometimes I want to look at only maybe the first 2: so [10, 176, 12] I'd take the first two and use "10176".

Comment: @MH175 Matt beat me to the punch, if you're looking for performance, you're much better off using a struct hard coded to use 2 or 3 values, and an `Int` as the key. This gets rid of the reference counting and heap overhead of arrays and strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is performance sensitive, then you'll probably want to avoid using arrays for data that's fixed to have two or three members. Arrays have buffers allocated on the heap, and those buffers need to be reference counted. Both of these facts have performance implications. They're negligible in the vast majority of cases, but in tight loops handling lots of data (e.g. network switching logic), you want to avoid them.

Try something like this:

```
struct TwoByteAddress: Hashable {
    let a: UInt8
    let b: UInt8

    init(_ a: UInt8, _ b: UInt8) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    static func ==(lhs: TwoByteAddress, rhs: TwoByteAddress) -> Bool {
        return lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return Int(a) << 8 | Int(b)
    }
}

struct ThreeByteAddress: Hashable {
    let twoByteAddress: TwoByteAddress
    let c: UInt8

    init(_ a: UInt8, _ b: UInt8, _ c: UInt8) {
        self.twoByteAddress = TwoByteAddress(a, b)
        self.c = c
    }

    static func ==(lhs: ThreeByteAddress, rhs: ThreeByteAddress) -> Bool {
        return lhs.twoByteAddress == rhs.twoByteAddress && lhs.c == rhs.c
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return twoByteAddress.hashValue << 8 | Int(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is for handling network stuff. Incoming data needs to be funneled into buckets. The bucket (the dictionary) is a list of all the different objects that need to be notified when this address comes in. It's kind of like a NotificationCenter, but I maintain the list of observers myself.

Comment: @MH175 Then this should do the trick! Should be really fast, since these structs are heap allocated. Also, the `hashValue` computation is MUCH faster generating and concatenating strings of these

Comment: @MH175 Do you need to be able to handle a heterogeneous collection of 2 and 3 byte addresses?

Comment: Yes-- actually up to 4 bytes. For example I can do 1 byte for all addresses starting with 255, which covers [255, x, x, x]. Or I can go one level deeper and do [255, 0] which covers [255, 0, x, x], etc.

Comment: @MH175 Wait, are these just subnet masks?

Comment: Ha, I know it looks like it! But it's for something totally different :-) Similar idea I guess!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151450/discussion-between-alexander-and-mh175).

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you're going to all the overhead of making a string in the first place. You've got small Ints, so why not calculate a unique Int as the key:

```
let address = [10, 176, 12]
let key = address[0] * 255 * 255 + address[1] * 255 + address[2]
```

That's extremely fast and self-hashing, and the original components can easily be extracted by rule.

Alternatively you could use a custom struct of three Int properties, on which you've implemented Hashable (by that same rule) and Equatable (by an obvious rule).